# Is there a way to use "get" for a Linked list as you would in an ArrayList.

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list

I am trying to use the get function as I do in an Array list but it's not working I wanted to know if there was any way to do so.

```
private ArrayList<OneFace> face= new ArrayList<OneFace>();
private LinkedList<String> friend = new LinkedList<String>(); ;

for (int i = 0 ; i< profiles; i++)
    {
    String arrayName = face.get(i).getName();
            System.out.println(arrayName);
     LinkedList<String> linkName = friend.getlink(i).getFriend();
            System.out.println(linkName);
    }
```

---

**This works**

```
 String arrayName = face.get(i).getName();
```

---

**This doesn't work***

```
 LinkedList<String> linkName = friend.getlink(i).getFriend();
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What error are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since both `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` implement the `List` interface, they both have the `get()` method. Note that you are trying to use `getlink()` which doesn't exist.

However, if you are trying to access an element at a given index, you most likely should use `ArrayList`. `LinkedList` is intended for use when you want to iterate over the list in a sequential manner.

Answer (score 0):

It is working, you have a `LinkedList<String>` so when you call [`LinkedList#get(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#get%28int%29) you get a `String`.

```
String f = friend.get(i);
```

Comment: Sounds like you don't have any `String`(s) in your `LinkedList`.

Comment: @huemanny You are using `i` as both the index for the `face` list and the `friend` list. This doesn't seem like a good idea to me.